# HELM condition statement using configmap value

Tags: if-statement, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have a `values.yaml` with content

```
efslogs:
 enables: true 
 somekey: somevalue`
```

I have `deployment.yaml` where I have a condition

```
env:
 - name: SOME_ENV_VAR
   value: SOME_VALUE
{{- if .Values.efslogs.enabled }}
  - name: EFS_DRIVE_MOUNTES
    value: "true"
{{- end}}
```

What I want to do, is move efslogs block to configmap like
`efsconfig.efslogs.enabled: true`

so the question is there any way to put this configmap reference in the if condition ?

like

```
{{- if <referance to my efsconfig.efslogs.enabled> }}
  - name: EFS_DRIVE_MOUNTES
    value: "true"
{{- end}}
```

thank you

Comment: where the `efsconfig.efslogs.enabled: true` will be configured? in an existing configmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes can do this on its own and you don't need Helm templating here.

When you [Define container environment variables using ConfigMap data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data) you can [provide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#optional-configmaps) an `optional: true` setting.  This sets the environment variable if the ConfigMap key is defined, and ignores it if it's not.

```yaml
env:
  - name: EFS_DRIVE_MOUNTES
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}
        key: efsconfig.efslogs.enabled
        optional: true
```

When you build the ConfigMap, you can provide the value or not.

```yaml
data:
{{- with .Values.efslogs.enabled }}
  efsconfig.efslogs.enabled: {{ quote . }}
{{- end }}
```

Note that the only thing it's possible to do with this setup is pass through the actual ConfigMap value as-is.  You can't transform the value, or set the environment variable to some fixed value if the ConfigMap key exists at all.

Nothing stops you from using Helm conditionals in the Deployment YAML file too, which can satisfy some of these more complex cases.  That is, keep the original conditional you have, but change the value to a `configMapKeyRef:` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the lookup function that was introduced in Helm 3.1:

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function

`The lookup function can be used to look up resources in a running cluster. The synopsis of the lookup function is lookup apiVersion, kind, namespace, name -> resource or resource list.`